# MacBook Pro dead screen with update to High Sierra

Tags: macbook-pro, hardware, screen, software

My MacBook Pro 15” 2012 Retina screen is completely black. This happened right after I updated to High Sierra. I tried doing all the resets, and at some point I realized that I could flashlight the screen from behind the logo, so I tried more things. Suddenly the screen turned on when I turned on the computer, and I could see the apple logo, but then it went black again - and now I can’t see the screen when I put a flashlight to it, for some reason.

Does anyone know what I can do? Or alternatively, is there a way for me to screenshare with AirPlay that I can access without being able to see the screen?

Answer (score 1):

Do you get the normal startup screen with the Apple logo? Or is it **always** black from the instant you turn it on?

You could try an external monitor if you have access to one, you could also try holding Shift at startup to see if booting into safe mode changes things.

And if those don't work it may be time to make an appointment with an Apple genius or other local repair shop.

Comment: It is always black, and doing the shift startup doesn’t change anything. My HDMI port has been broken for some time, so I can’t use that, and I don’t have anything I can use for the Mini DisplayPort.

Comment: Time for a visit to a repair shop...